# What is WIFI_P2P (type 13) among NetworkInfo types?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-wifi, network-protocols

I got the array of `NetworkInfo` from `ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo()` and printed out the details.

The `ConnectivityManager` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_BLUETOOTH) only enumerates types `0` to `9` as constants (like `TYPE_WIFI` or `TYPE_MOBILE`). However I found additional types on my device *(SGS3 I9305)*:

- `10: mobile_fota`
- `11: mobile_ims`
- `12: mobile_cbs`
- `13: WIFI_P2P`

While I would also like to know what the types `10` to `12` mean, I am particularly interested in the last one, `WIFI_P2P`.

Is this the "Portable Wi-Fi hotspot" feature or the "Wi-Fi Direct"<sup>1</sup> feature? Or something else, like creating an "ad-hoc wireless network" on *Microsoft Windows*, and then connecting the device to it?

Please do provide your sources. Also, what other undocumented network types are out there? And can these **undocumented** type numbers vary from devices to devices or from manufacturers to manufacturers?

<sup>1</sup>The description for [wifi-direct](/questions/tagged/wifi-direct) indeed mentions "point to point networking" but I want to be sure the network type `13` is referring to this extension and **not** anything else.

Comment: @user3811037 Please post an answer, not suggest an edit. The link you posted has some good info. Quote all the **relevant** info in the answer. Also what project is the link from?

Comment: The link referred to in the previous comment is [this](http://developer.oesf.biz/em/developer/reference/eggplant/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). It is a documentation of some embedded implementation of Android, called the *EggPlant*. Interestingly, all the types mentioned have constants there (suggesting they may not be manufacturer-specific). `TYPE_MOBILE_FOTA`: Over the air Adminstration. `TYPE_MOBILE_IMS`: IP Multimedia Subsystem. `TYPE_MOBILE_CBS`: Carrier Branded Services. `TYPE_WIFI_P2P`: A Wi-Fi p2p connection. Only requesting processes will have access to the peers connected.